# docker как работает

Tags: docker

такой вопрос, развернул у себя 3 докер контейнера, и я так понимаю, что они общаются между собой, и тк у меня в docker-compose стоит volume, который направляет папку с проектом в докер контейнер, то получается, что php видит сайт.

В общем-то все работает, но, получается, если я захочу развернуть еще 1 сайт на докере, я также запущу еще несколько контейнеров почти с тем же самым, чтобы просто иметь два разных сайта на локалке.

Разве не должен докер как бы экстендить систему? То есть я запускаю nginx в докере и все, он работает изолированно, но я могу обращаться к nginx прямо из системы, а не из докер контейнера.

То есть у меня сайт запускается изолированно с тремя связанными контейнерами, а может он должен запускаться на самой системе, и работать как будто все эти приложения установлены на локальном компе.

Хз правильно ли я выразил мысль вообще

Comment: Вы видите разницу между запуском "сервиса" на локальной машине или в контейнере?  это первое на что надо ответить.